# Python mysql xampp

Tags: python, mysql

i installed xampp server. I want to access MySQL database through python. I tried to install MySQL-python package. It needs visual studio which I don't want to install.

I tried through MySQL connectors, but it is not allowing to do so.

How can I access MySQL database through python?

Comment: Can you give us the code you tried so far? Also what is the exact mysql modul you installed and what version of python are you using? Also an error message would be good

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(user="user_name",passwd="password",db="database_name",unix_socket="mysql.sock file path")
```

OR try running, `python manage.py runserver`

OR once check your default setting of database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'database_name',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'user_name',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306'                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```